# ¿Como desglosar una cantidad entera en billetes de diferentes numeraciones?

Tags: c#

Escribir el método "desgloseBillete" que solicite un valor entero y devuelva la cantidad correspondiente de billetes. 
Los billetes utilizados son:  $1, $5, $10, $20, $50, $100
Ejemplo: importe = 157 {$100(1), $50(1), $5(1), $1(2)}

Este es el código que he tratado de volver funcional de momento, aunque se que tiene muchos errores lógicos obvios. (Es de un tercero y solo le estoy haciendo el favor porque no sabe ocupar mucho que sigamos el foro)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Alfredo
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Declaracion de variables
        Double Dinero, B1 = 0, B5 = 0, B10 = 0, B20 = 0, B50 = 0, B100 = 0;
        //Entrada de datos
        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la cantidad de dinero a desglosar: ");
        Dinero = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        //Proceso
        if (Dinero >= 100)
            B100 = Math.Abs(Dinero) / 100;
        Dinero = Dinero - (B100 * 100);
        if (Dinero >= 50)
            B50 = Math.Abs(Dinero) / 50;
        Dinero = Dinero - (B100 * 50);
        if (Dinero >= 20)
            B100 = Math.Abs(Dinero) / 20;
        Dinero = Dinero - (B20 * 20);
        if (Dinero >= 10)
            B10 = Math.Abs(Dinero) / 10;
        Dinero = Dinero - (B10 * 10);
        if (Dinero >= 5)
            B5 = Math.Abs(Dinero) / 5;
        Dinero = Dinero - (B5 * 5);
        if (Dinero >= 1)
            B1 = Math.Abs(Dinero) / 1;
        Dinero = Dinero - (B1 * 1);
        //Salida
        Console.WriteLine("La cantidad en billetes de $100: " + B100);
        Console.WriteLine("La cantidad en billetes de $50: " + B50);
        Console.WriteLine("La cantidad en billetes de $20: " + B20);
        Console.WriteLine("La cantidad en billetes de $10: " + B10);
        Console.WriteLine("La cantidad en billetes de $5: " + B5);
        Console.WriteLine("La cantidad en billetes de $1: " + B1);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: ¿es decir que quieres que lo hagamos por ti? *just kidding...* ¿Has intentado algo? Con el código que tengas ponlo en la pregunta para saber mejor cómo orientarte y encontrar la mejor solución ;)

Answer (score -1):

De acuerdo a tu ejemplo y esto sin tener en cuenta limites de billetes, yo lo haria asi:

```
string DesglosaBilletes(int importe)//Retorna cadena de texto, recibe entero
    {
        string resultado = "";// variable que se regresara

        int[] billetes = { 1, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100 }; //arreglo de billetes
        int faltante= importe, cantidad;
        Array.Sort(billetes);//ordena el arreglo en forma ascendente
        Array.Reverse(billetes);//revierte el orden del arreglo para tenerlo de forma descendente

        foreach (int x in billetes)
        {
            if(faltante >= x)// si el faltante es mayor al billete actual se procede al desglose
            {
                cantidad = faltante / x;//cuantos billes utilizara
                faltante -= x * cantidad;//se reduce el faltante con los billetes utilizados
                resultado += "$" + x + "(" + cantidad + "), ";//concatenaciones
            }

        }
        if (faltante == 0)//comprobar si el importe fue totalmente desglozado
            resultado = "Importe: $" + importe + "{" + resultado + "}";
        else
            resultado = "No se puede desglosar esa cantidad";

        return resultado;
    }
```

Saludos.

Comment: Si el valor del array será escríto a mano, ¿Por qué necesito las llamadas a `Array.Sort()` y `Array.Reverse()`? ¿No es más facil escribirlos de manera ordenada?

Comment: Asi es solo lo puse porque creo que le podria ser util ya que este ejercicio se podria volver mas complejo, siendo configurable, por eso la intencion de ponerlo ordenado ascendentemente desde su declaracion, asi como creo que tambien podria poner la cantidad de billetes de cada denominacion disponibles.